# Redirect user to the appropriate page from ASP classic login page

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a website on which certain pages are secured with a login page written in vbscript (framework is asp classic). Given that the username is "foo" and the password is "bar", the login page currently accepts the username and password and then redirects the user to a default page. We will call it "page1". Below is the code:

```
Response.Buffer = True
If lcase(Request.Form("username")) = "foo" AND lcase(Request.Form("password")) = "bar" then
Session.Contents("foo") = "1"
Response.Redirect("page1.asp")
Else
Response.Redirect("failure.asp")
End If
```

This works but the user will always be redirected to the same page, regardless of which page they were trying to reach. I would like the user to be redirected to the page they were trying to reach before being sent tho the login page. Supposing the user wanted to go to "page2", I tried the following code:

```
Response.Buffer = True
If Request.ServerVariables("URL")= "http://www.mysite.com.com/page2.asp" AND lcase(Request.Form("username")) = "foo" AND lcase(Request.Form("password")) = "bar" then
Session.Contents("Dealer") = "1"
Response.Redirect("page2.asp")
ElseIf lcase(Request.Form("username")) = "foo" AND lcase(Request.Form("password")) = "bar" then
Session.Contents("foo") = "1"
Response.Redirect("page1.asp")
Else
Response.Redirect("failure.asp")
End If
```

This does not work, which is probably because

```
Request.ServerVariables("URL")
```

is pulling the url from the login page. Does anyone know how to send the user to the page that was originally requested?

Thanks in advance for any help/advice!

Comment: Can you post the code that does the redirection to the login page as some solutions would require this to be modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your login form page add a hidden field for the referring page and populate the value like this:

```
<input name="referer" type="hidden" value="<%= Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER") %> />
```

Then redirect to this page once the form is submitted successfully:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.Form("referer"))
```

Comment: Thanks John! This worked nicely - was banging my head against it for hours.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about "classic asp", nor VB script.

But what about the approach of adding the desired page (requiring login) in a querystring ?

forcing to land the user on login.aspx?redirectUrl=desiredPage.asp

then when login is done, you redirect to the page by retrieving it from the querystring ?

This page explains it better.

[ASP.NET: directing user to login page, after login send user back to page requested originally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569426/asp-net-directing-user-to-login-page-after-login-send-user-back-to-page-reques)

Comment: That is a good idea, but in this case it doesn't work. Right now any request for accesss to the directory with page 1 and 2 redirects to login page, and appended query strings do not pass. Howver I will read the full docs you linked me too and see if there are other issues.

Comment: @HelloWorld - would be nice if you at least upvote answers which was helpful for you or even better marked what was answer to your question.

Comment: @All Blond None of the answers have resolved the problem. Some of the answers have helped me (yours included) and when I have enough rep to up vote (6 more points to go!) I will go back and do so.

Comment: If those answers did not help you then your question is incorrectly formulated. Because in classic asp only one road  is untouched for your question - is use of cookies but believe me you do not want to go that way.

Answer (score 1):

Every secured page should have some header code like this:

```
If Not Session("LoggedIn") Then
    Response.Redirect "login.asp?r=" & Server.UrlEncode(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME"))
End If
```

I typically put this into an include file called "private.asp" and make sure to include it at the top of every page that should be secured.

In your login page, after you've successfully logged in the user, check your querystring value to see if you should forward the user back to an originally requested page:

```
' After successful login...
strReturnURL = Request.QueryString("r")

If Len(strReturnURL) > 0 Then
    Response.Redirect strReturnURL
Else
    ' Send them to your homepage...
    Response.Redirect "/"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

your signin page URL should look like that:

http://domain.com/login.asp?urlstr=page2.asp

```
Response.Buffer = True
dim redirecturl
 redirecturl = Request("urlstr")
If  lcase(Request.Form("username")) = "foo" AND lcase(Request.Form("password")) = "bar"  and len(redirecturl)>0 then
Session("Dealer") = "1"
Response.Redirect(redirecturl)
ElseIf lcase(Request.Form("username")) = "foo" AND lcase(Request.Form("password")) = "bar" and len(redirecturl)=0  then
Session("foo") = "1"
Response.Redirect("login.asp")
Else
Response.Redirect("failure.asp")
End If
```

Comment: I don't think you can dimension a variable and assign it a value in one command in Classic ASP (dim redirecturl = Request("urlstr")). Try  Dim redirecturl : redirecturl = Request("urlstr") instead.

Comment: That's true @John but watch out they don't like to be corrected and you'll notice your answers getting downvoted.